# Pentatonic Scales Question

Tags: guitar, theory, scales

I'm learning the notes on the fret board and I just wanted to ask something about the pentatonic scales you see, A minor pentatonic is A C D E G on the 5th fret, but when I play it on the 2nd fret its G A C D E, can someone tell me what's the theory behind this? Thank you guys

Comment: Music works relatively - it's all about intervals from a starting note. All you've done is move the starting note so it all still works with itself, just a bit lower down the fretboard :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's the same scale, you just start on a different note. For example if you start on the 8th fret, you will play the notes `C, D, E, G, A`. It's all the same scale just where you start is different and there are many places you can play it on the neck of your guitar.

[image]

This picture shows everywhere that you can play the A minor pentatonic scale. The red dots are the root note of the scale the A in this case.

Once you remember the patterns you can easily shift it to any key. Just find the root that you want and the scale falls into place.

Comment: It's worth it to learn [all five patterns.](http://guitarteacher.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/CAGED-in-G-3.png)  It's all the same scale, just different places to play it. Just remember where the roots are because those are important when improvising. Also, A minor pentatonic is the same as C Major pentatonic, so if you play the same scale but start and end on C you get a Major Pentatonic form. All five shapes can be used for both Major and minor, only the position of the root notes change.

Answer (score 3):

I believe understanding this would be much easier if we differentiated between patterns and shapes. The pattern of a major pentatonic scale is 22323, a minor pentatonic scale follows the pattern 32232. The numbers refer to the semi-tone distances between the notes. So the pattern for the major pentatonic A gives us the notes A B C# E F# back to A, and the pattern for the minor pentatonic scale in A results in A C D E G back to A. The respective first shapes of each pattern start with the root note on the sixth (low E) string.

Answer (score 2):

Each of the five patterns would be a mode of that pentatonic scale. Adding the flat five (of your original A minor pentatonic) in each of those positions opens up new improvisational ideas too.